# How to setup Spring/Heroku/postgres SSL datasource

Tags: spring, postgresql, ssl, heroku

I'm trying to create a datasource from my Heroku/Spring application to postgres.heroku.com postgres database. Here is my `applicationContext.xml` snippet.

```xml
<bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://url/dstabase"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

But when I run the app, tomcat gives this error:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.11.12.13", user "username", database "database", SSL off)
```

How can I configure it to use SSL? I need it in order to stablish a connection against postgres.heroku.com

Comment: Got to admit I've never used PostgreSQL or Heroku but am guessing the following should help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely

Comment: @DB5 that sounds correct, you should put it as an answer

Comment: how did you resolve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to extend your JDBC connection URL with the relevant ssl information.

Your JDBC connection URL will need to include the following:

```
ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

So in your case the URL would be:

```
jdbc:postgresql://url/dstabase?ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Source for this info:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely

Comment: this setting opens a SSL connection, but does not validate the certificates. If you have the chance to use certificates as described here: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/ssl-client.html

Comment: for me it worked using 
...?ssl=true&&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.DefaultJavaSSLFactory

Answer (score 5):

Following worked for me:

```
jdbc:postgresql://url/databaseName?sslmode=require&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

I'd to change `ssl=true` to `sslmode=require`

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful for me too...!!

Answer (score 4):

When connecting to Heroku Postgres with jdbc, you will also sometimes get an error unless you add the SSL parameters to the url:

```
ssl=true
sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

Answer (score 3):

It worked for me:

```
  <bean id="securityDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
    </bean>
```

The mistake I was doing was using an & instead of `&amp;` (silly I know)

```
 ?ssl=true&amp;sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
```

and yes the link definitely is helpful:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely

AND Keep in mind: 
in this link, jdbc:**postgres**://host.. is used, which might not be suitable for you (use **postgresql** instead) if **No suitable Sql driver error occurs**