# JDBC hostname error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am expirencing a problem with the JDBC driver. My database is at `postgres://...` but the driver only works with `postgresql://...`. What should I do?

I am trying to connect to a heroku postgres database from java.

CODE:

```
Connection conn = null;
```

Below I am trying with `postgresql://`

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://bfjxvagjalvmcu:n9Y2VO0myQ5sgWVrzJbLX59TD3@ec2-54-204-15-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/*****&username=******&password=******&ssl=true");
```

And I get the error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
```

And if I use this code, with `postgres`

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgres://bfjxvagjalvmcu:n9Y2VO0myQ5sgWVrzJbLX59TD3@ec2-54-204-15-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/****&username=******&password=****&ssl=true");
```

I get the error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgres://bfjxvagjalvmcu:n9Y2VO0myQ5sgWVrzJbLX59TD3@ec2-54-204-15-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/*******&username=********&password=*******&ssl=true
```

Comment: Could you show exception? Would be much more efficient to track down issue.

Comment: My Postgres connection starts with "jdbc:postgresql://..."

Comment: "*The connection attempt failed*" seems to indicate that your connection credentials are wrong somehow. I don't see any indication that there is a "hostname" error. Maybe a SSL problem: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9386803/330315 or here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11832361/330315

Comment: `jdbc:postgresql:` is correct one.

Comment: Are you sure, that your machine can access your RDS? There is an [article](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html) regarding VPC configuration at AWS, which may help you.

Comment: What happens when you run `ping ec2-54-204-15-41.compute-1.amazonaws.com` on the command line of your operating system?

Comment: Before connecting to the real database test connection url with Eclipse Data Tools.